# Mount Zip on OSX

Tags: macos, zip

Is there any way to mount a zip (or tar, or any compressed file archive) as a volume on OSX?

If this is a stupid question for some reason (the structure of zip archives), that would be good to know too.

Answer (score 13):

Yep, if you install FUSE (Filesystem in User Space) and the [fuse-zip extension](http://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/). There is a GUI of sorts for FUSE called [MacFuse](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) that I'd recommend using.

You can use FUSE to mount all sorts of things including files over ssh or flickr ([yes really!](http://manishrjain.googlepages.com/flickrfs))

Comment: Fascinating. Thanks for that and plus 11. Well, plus 1, can't do 11 just yet.

Comment: It's a pretty interesting bit of software - the sshfs is really handy for pretending that remote files are local.

Comment: and realizing that your hosting provider (GoDaddy in this case) breaks the connection every few minutes just for fun. Ugh.

Comment: Nice... That's ridiculous!

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer simple drag-and-drop then you can use this app with MacFUSE too:

https://www.etresoft.com/#products (scroll down to eTreZip)

Comment: posted in 2010, have you tried this?

Comment: Hi, I have OSX 10.6, and it works nicely. Somebody else has to try it with the Lions. :)

Answer (score 1):

**[Archive Mounter](https://github.com/ivoronin/ArchiveMounter)** does the job.

> An app to mount archives like disk images in macOS. It currently supports ZIP and RAR archives.

#### Usage

You can run app directly and choose an archive to mount or use it from Finder's *Open With* context menu.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thank you for your contribution, but could you read [how to recommend software in my answer](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) (especially the bits in **bold**) and [edit your answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1314271/edit) to reflect the guidance please? :)